# Export & Import - Single IIS WebSites using powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

Is there any way to export and import the single iis website from one server to another.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, everything is in the IISAdministration Powershell module, using the `Export-IISConfiguration` cmdlet. You can visit this [MS docs link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/export-iisconfiguration?view=win10-ps)  to review what cmdlets best suit your specific needs.

You can also use a couple of commands:
To Export website:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /config /xml > c:\sites.xml
```

To Import the website:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < c:\sites.xml
```

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: This still works for IIS 8 and IIS 10, just tested it
Also good to know that this will import and export ALL items, including the "default website".  So you will get an error if you try to import it and its already there.  Make sure to delete them first (if you can afford to do that).
Also this will not export the App Pools, only the value of the App Pool associated with the Web Site.  You will need another process to Import/Export that.
`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml > c:\apppools.xml`
and 
`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < c:\apppools.xml`

Comment: Be careful with the `appcmd list apppool /config` command though - it exports the application pool passwords in clear text!